# Backbone.js: Elegant way to check if data ready and if the dataset is empty

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking for a better solution for two things:

- How can I understand if the data is fetched and ready, I use `BasicDealList.on("reset", function(){})` to understand if the data is fetched from ajax and parsed and ready to be used but it feels dirty.
- If an empty JSON comes from fetching such as `{}`, it still shows BasicDealList.length as 1 while it should be 0 thus I was forced to check if the first element is empty via `collection.length == 1 && jQuery.isEmptyObject(BasicDealList.toJSON()[0]` which is very ugly.

Here is the code:

```
BasicDeal = Backbone.Model.extend();    
BasicDealCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BasicDeal,
    url: '/some/ajax/url/',
});
BasicDealList = new BasicDealCollection();

BasicDealList.on("reset", function(collection, response){
    isEmpty = collection.length == 1 && jQuery.isEmptyObject(BasicDealList.toJSON()[0]);
    if (isEmpty){
    // render no deal found html
    }
    else{ 
    // render list of deals
    }
}
BasicDealList.fetch();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you don't like listening for `reset`, you can pass a callback directly to `.fetch()`:

```
BasicDealList.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response){
        // ...
    }
});
```

If, later in your app, you want to know whether you've fetched the data already, you could usually just check `BasicDealList.length`. If you want to avoid making repeated requests for collections that are actually empty on the server, you'll probably need to work out a custom solution, e.g. setting a flag on `.fetch()`:

```
BasicDealList.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response){
        BasicDealList.fetched = true;
        // ...
    }
});
```

As for the empty data issue, you should be returning `[]` from the server instead of `{}`. Backbone's Collection calls `this.add(models, ...)` within `.reset()`, and `.add()` checks whether the `models` argument is an array; if it's not, it wraps it in one:

```
models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
```

So passing `{}` will result in `models` set to `[{}]`, which is not what you want. If you can't control the server, you could do the check for `{}` in a custom `.parse()` method, returning `[]` if it's found.

Answer (score 13):

I know this question has already been answered but here is an alternative.

```
BasicDealCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BasicDeal,
    url: '/some/ajax/url/',
});

myCollection = new BasicDealCollection()
deferred = myCollection.fetch()

$.when(deferred).then(function() {
  // do stuff when we have the data.
});
```

The key benefit of this is that we are using the "when" function. The "when" function gives us the ability to check multiple fetch calls and do one success.

```
$.when(deferredOne, deferredTwo, deferredThree).then(function() {
  // do stuff when we have the data.
});
```

Also, if we stored the deferred object into a variable, we can do things like this. The variable will be a flag to let us know that we already loaded the data.

```
if (deferred.state() === "resolved") {
    // do stuff when we have the data.
}
```

When we call fetch() on a collection it returns a jQuery deferred object. A jQuery deferred object can be in 3 states, "pending", "rejected" or "resolved" and once we have the data, it will set the state of the deferred object to resolved.

Answer (score 7):

We needed a way to tell if a RelationalModel's relation had been fetched or not.  This is our solution (in Coffeescript).

```
initialize: (objects, options) ->
  @fetched = false
  @listenTo @, 'sync', -> @fetched = true
```