# Backbone model override fetch using easyxdm

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to override backbone model fetch function using easyXDM, the reason for using easyXDM is because the server is located on different domain.

here is the fetch code:

```
     fetch: function(options)
     {
        model = this;
        a = true;
        this.xhr.request({
           url: "http://server.dev:9000/users/" + this.id,
           method: "GET"
        }, function(response){
           console.log(response.data);

           var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.data);

           if (jsonResponse.status == 'success'){
             model.set({
                firstName : jsonResponse.data.first_name,
                lastName :   jsonResponse.data.last_name,
                email : jsonResponse.data.email,
                companyName : jsonResponse.data.company.name,
                companyId : jsonResponse.data.company.id
             }) 
           }
        });

     }
```

And here is code on the controller fetching the model

```
    var user = new UserModel({id : id});
    user.fetch();
    alert(user.get('firstName')); // display undefined
```

So the problem is whenever I call fetch, the model is still not populated yet.
I am thinking because the easyXDM request is async so its not yet populated.
Is there anyway to make sure that the model is populated and ready to use?
perhaps using a callback, any direction on how to create a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question initially.  Fetch is async with or without easyXDM, so you have to either implement the onsuccess callback of fetch, or check if the model is set (using length or other method) before doing any operations on it.  This post may help as well:

[Backbone.js: Elegant way to check if data ready and if the dataset is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016562/backbone-js-elegant-way-to-check-if-data-ready-and-if-the-dataset-is-empty)

Comment: thats right but is there any other way to make this work other than trigger an event?

Comment: Yes, using the success callback which he's mentioned in the answer

Comment: Sorry, that comment of hieexone's was before I edited my answer entirely

Comment: Thanks Jordan for your explanation, but I'm still confused on how to trigger the success callback from easyXDM, can you provide a sample code that works on my situation? My understanding is that I should 
do this `user.fetch({success: function(){alert("model is populated");}});` Is this correct? but on the model how do I specify that it is successful so it will go the success callback? Thanks

Comment: Nvm got it! I just need to call the options.success() on the easyXDM request success part.Thanks for your help!